# SQL Subquery w/LEFT JOIN causing Invalid Object Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2000

I have a query with the following structure:

**EDIT** Original structure of the query wasn't quite representative.

```
SELECT   A
        ,B
        ,C
        ,D

FROM ( SELECT id,A
       FROM myTable 
       WHERE conditions 
       GROUP BY id,A) MainQuery
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, B, C 
           FROM myView
           WHERE id IN
             (
                  SELECT DISTINCT id
                  FROM MainQuery
             )
          ) sub1
   ON sub1.B = MainQuery.A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MainQuery.id, D
           FROM myOtherView
           WHERE sub1.id IN
             (
               SELECT DISTINCT id
               FROM MainQuery
             )
           ) sub2
   ON sub2.D = sub1.C
```

When I run the query, I get the error message `Invalid object name 'MainQuery'.` When I comment out the `LEFT JOINs` and the fields they feed in the `SELECT` statement, the query runs just fine. I've also tried `AS MainQuery`, but I get the same result.

I suspect it has something to do with scope. Where I'm trying to `SELECT DISTINCT id FROM MainQuery`, is `MainQuery` out of scope for the `WHERE` subquery within `sub1`?

For context, I've been tasked with rewriting a query that used temp tables into a query that can be used in a report deployed on SSRS 2000. My `MainQuery`, `sub1`, and `sub2` were temp tables in the original query. Those temp tables used subqueries within them, which I've preserved in my translation. But the original query had the advantage of creating each temp table separately, and then joining the results. Temp tables and subqueries are new to me, so I'm not sure how to adapt between the two, or if that's even the right approach.

Comment: You can't use MainQuery in your derived table that you are left joining to (sub1).  It doesn't exist in that scope.

Comment: That's what I thought might be the case. Is there any way I can use it? Declare it as a table variable, for example?

Comment: Make it a CTE, then you can refer to it in your query.

Comment: @Andrew, Though I'm writing the query in SSRS 2008 R2, I'm deploying to SSRS 2000. Can I deploy a query with a CTE to SSRS 2000? My understanding was that I cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL for your MainQuery is invalid.  Run it by itself and see:

```
SELECT A, id
   FROM myTable 
   WHERE conditions 
   GROUP BY A
```

You can't select A and id, but only group by A.  Either you need to also group by id, or wrap id in an aggregate function like min, or max.

With that addressed it looks like your other issue is that you say "LEFT JOIN" but then place the column of your LEFT JOINED table on the left hand side of your where clause.  See below where I flip sub1.B and MainQuery.A in the JOIN.

```
SELECT   A
        ,B
        ,C
        ,D

FROM ( SELECT A, id
       FROM myTable 
       WHERE conditions 
       GROUP BY A,id) MainQuery
LEFT JOIN nutherTable sub1
on MainQuery.A = sub1.B
and MainQuery.id = sub1.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT D ...) sub2
   ON sub1.C = sub2.D
```

Comment: Thanks, @bill-gregg. I did forget that in my example above. But that's not the problem with my query. As I mentioned above, when I comment out the `LEFT JOINs` and the fields that they're supposed to return, I don't get any errors. The MainQuery is valid, but thanks for helping me correct my typo above.

Comment: Why are you " id in ( select distinct id from MainQuery)" instead of just joining to MainQuery on id?

Comment: Short answer, the full query is a lot longer than the above. I've cut out a lot for the sake of simplicity. I'll do another edit to see if I can clear up what's going on in the original query.

Comment: Again though, just selecting (id in (select distinct id from MainQuery)) seems superfluous to just joining to MainQuery on ID.  And make sure that your WHERE conditions are sequenced correctly based on what you are LEFT JOINING to.  The LEFT side of the = should be what you know you will have and the RIGHT side of the = should be what you might have.

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying. I went this route because I was just trying to mimic the original structure of the query as much as possible. I saw what the temp tables were doing, and I tried to do the same with subqueries, partly because I honestly haven't been able to figure out how to join all the parts. I wanted to try a different direction. I appreciate your feedback. It's given me another way to look at the issue. Thanks!